# ImageSharp and System.Drawing Jpeg encoding differences

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg, system.drawing, imagesharp

I'm reading a .png file as a byte array and trying to encode the image as a jpeg by using both System.Drawing (*Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8*) and SixLabors ImageSharp (*3.0.1*).

I need the following methods to output the same file contents, so that they can be used interchangeably:

```csharp
internal static void SaveBytesToJpg_ImageSharp(byte[] imageBytes, string fileName)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        using (var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load<Rgba32>(ms))
        {

            JpegEncoder jp = new JpegEncoder()
            {
                Quality = 100,
                ColorType = JpegEncodingColor.YCbCrRatio420 
            };
            
            image.SaveAsJpeg(fileName, jp);
        }
    }
}

internal static void SaveBytesToJpg_SystemDrawing(byte[] imageBytes, string fileName)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))
        {
            EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            ImageCodecInfo ici = null;

            // Use codec for better quality.
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);

            // color space seems to be  YCbCr 4:2:0

            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
                    ici = codec;
            }
            try
            {
                image.Save(fileName, ici, myEncoderParameters);
            }
            finally
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myEncoderParameters.Param.Length; i++)
                {
                    myEncoderParameters.Param[i].Dispose();
                }

                myEncoderParameters.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By running this simple test, where I save the same image using these two different methods:

```csharp
var imgAsByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("path.png");

SaveBytesToJpg_ImageSharp(imgAsByteArray, "path1.jpg");
SaveBytesToJpg_SystemDrawing(imgAsByteArray, "path2.jpg");
```

I get two files slightly different in size (430kb vs 470kb), and, by inspecting the results with [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/), I can see some pixels are different.

What settings should I set for the encoders to make sure that the output is the same for the System.Drawing version and the ImageSharp version?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such a thing as a "System.Drawing" JPG compatibility bit-level mode in ImageSharp.

The output of System.Drawing's JPG depends on the operating system it is running on, while ImageSharp is designed to be operating system-agnostic. Therefore, the output of System.Drawing is not always 100% identical to the output of other instances of System.Drawing.